# How to make the page be refreshed after an Onclick is fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

So I have some information I show a user about their account. However, an administrator can see this page, and decide to click "Activate" or "Deactivate" on a user.

**Expected behavior:**
If the administrator presses Activate on an inactive account, the information queries the database and displays at the top that the user's account is active. And the success message is displayed.

**The current behavior:**
If the administrator presses Activate on an inactive account, **the information doesn't requery**, it still says the user's account is INACTIVE. And the success message is displayed.

I'm using OnClick and runat="server" on the buttons. And the information table that queries the database is in **Page_Load()**. I'm not using the "IsPostBack" or anything, so it should refresh the information.

Do I have to put a **"Reload()"** or **"Refresh()"** or **"DataBind()"** type function at the end of my "btnUpdate_**OnClick**(object sender, EventArgs e)" function? How would I do this?

I just don't understand why the event lifecycle won't just reload the page completely.

EDIT:

Some simplified code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

      if (Request["uid"] != null)
          userID = Int32.Parse(Request["uid"]);

      UserDAO ud = new UserDAO();
      tblUser u = ud.GetUser(userID);
      AccountStatus.Text = (((Boolean)u.ActiveOrNot) ? "Active" : "Inactive") + "<br />";

 }

 protected void btnActivate_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      UserDAO udao = new UserDAO();
      int userBeingEdited = -1;

      if (Request["uid"] != null)
      {
          userBeingEdited = Int32.Parse(Request["uid"]);
      }
      if (udao.ActivateUser(userBeingEdited))
      {
          DisplayError("This user has been activated.", true);
      }
 }
```

Where AccountStats is a Asp:label. And GetUser queries the database.

That's all the relevant code.

**I'm wondering why Onclick doesn't refresh the page and reload Page_Load() function!!**

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I'm not saving the state or anything.

Comment: What is happening in btnUpdate_Click and what in Page_Load? Do you requery and DataBind after the processing in btnUpdate_Click?

Comment: look at your question one more time and where you say you are not using isPostBack and where you say run at server.. "RUNAT=SERVER" is the key here..

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking... the page IS cycled when the postback happens. That's how it all works?

Comment: im prtty sure as @DJ_KRAZE says you need if(!PostBack) when using a runat=server

Comment: Why do I need that? I want everything to reload, I don't want to restrict any reloading of anything in Page_Load()----BTW I added New code at the TOP.

Comment: How about you post some actual code that you have .. and I am quite sure on of the guru's here will be more than happy to help you out..

Comment: where is this coming from if (Request["uid"] != null) are you using Session Variables anywhere.. also if you are using a DataGrid to display the data where is the Binding..? if not where is your Response.Write() you have to chill on your attitude a bit we are here to help..

Comment: Request["uid"] is getting the user id from the GET variable. EditUser.aspx?uid=15  for example. It would take 15, and query user 15 in the database. Don't you dare assume attitude when I have not shown anyone any attitude and simply replied as respectfully as possible, if you are assuming attitude, you are imagining it. I do truly get annoyed when people assume attitude or "tone" when there is no evidence of it from an internet comment without any audio. I don't use Response.Write or DataGrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnLoad` fires before event handlers like `btnActivate_OnClick`. Since you are displaying status in `OnLoad`, the changes made in the button's click event won't be reflected until the next page load.

You can put the code which displays the status into `OnPreRender`, which fires after event handlers, or you can add an additional method to display status.

```
private int _uid;

protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if( Request["uid"] != null )
    {
        _uid = Int32.Parse( Request["uid"] );
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException( "uid parameter is missing." );
    }

    DisplayStatus();
}

private void DisplayStatus()
{
    UserDAO ud = new UserDAO();
    tblUser u = ud.GetUser( _uid );
    AccountStatus.Text = ( ( (Boolean)u.ActiveOrNot ) ? "Active" : "Inactive" ) + "<br />";
}

protected void btnActivate_OnClick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    UserDAO udao = new UserDAO();
    int userBeingEdited = -1;

    if( _uid > default( int ) )
    {
        userBeingEdited = _uid;
    }
    if( udao.ActivateUser( userBeingEdited ) )
    {
        DisplayError( "This user has been activated.", true );
    }

    DisplayStatus();
}
```

Comment: And how would I fix this so that it does refresh? Is there a Refresh() function somewhere to re-load Page_OnLoad? Or maybe transfer the code to some other function and not Page_OnLoad??

Comment: @Dexter - see my code sample which manually updates the status or put the status code in PreRender.

Comment: Ah I see, so you would just call the code again directly, rather than reload Page_OnLoad function. What if I had put Page_Onload(); at the bottom of my Activate_Onclick---would that be too ridiculous? The reason I ask is because I have a lot of javascript variables also that need to be reloaded through the server's Page_OnLoad function and I don't want to add any AJAX.

Comment: @Dexter - Yes, that would probably work but you shouldn't call page events (like onload) manually. They are meant to be fired in a certain sequence by the base class. If there is a lot of functionality in OnLoad, abstract it to separate methods that you can call wherever you want.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'll just take most things out of the page_Onload and into their own function. I was just wondering what that might do.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what controls you use to show data on the page. Anyway you may try to call `this.DataBind()` (or `yourLabel.DataBind()` etc). Could you show some code?

Comment: I posted some code. I don't think DataBind() will work for my situation.

Comment: well, I see that your activation logic is execute AFTER label is updated. Try to change the label after activation is done. I mean that page_load is executed before XXX_click

Comment: Yes, I can retype out the code to change the label---but that seems redundant, why won't ASP.net provide a function for me to re-launch Page_OnLoad() from the Onclick function? Should I just go ahead and call Page_Onload() from the OnClick() directly?

Comment: Actually you do not need to set the label text on each request. ASP.NET keeps old values between requests using viewstate. So you just need to update that value once it was changed. Calling page_load is definitely not the way you should go. I'd recommend to extract the method that sets the text and call it from page_load for non-postbacks (initialization) as well from places where it is going to be changed (like your click handler)

Comment: funny that we are running the same discussion as with @tim medora :)

Comment: Yeah. I understand. But what do you mean by changing the value only without setting the text. How would I change the value of a label without doing label.Text = "new value".